# delphi debugging exclude system.pas

Tags: delphi, debugging, assembly, system

when debugging through VCL (use debug dcus must be on !) you have very often (in some situations most of the time) to step through assembly code, especially such routines like "_IntfClear".

(removing System.pas could not help, because then a popup appears frequently asking where system.pas resides)

Is there any chance to exclude the unit "system" from debugging ?

Comment: Well, you could put the non-debug DCUs .dcu file into the lib\debug folder. That would do what you ask but I'd certainly not recomend doing it!

Comment: You can also hackishly replace system.dcu with debug info with system.dcu w/o debug info.

Comment: Delphi XE7, one of the multi-platform template applications (New Project > Tabbed with Navigation) was doing exactly this, stepping into all the system units. It turns out, whoever created that template changed a bunch of project settings (including toggling `Debug DCU's`). Also, same template failed on 32bit apps (in project settings) - I had to completely delete Win32 from platforms and re-add it to make it work. I wonder if that person got fired from their job.

Answer (score 10):

Delphi's included DCU files are in the *Lib* folder. The debug versions are in the *Lib/Debug* folder. All the "Use debug DCUs" option does is control which of those two folders appears in your project's library path, so when your program is linked, one or the other set of DCU files is included.

Now that we've uncovered the magic of the "Use debug DCUs" option, we can take advantage of it. To exclude a certain DCU from debugging, enable "Use debug DCUs," and then simply find the debug version of the unit in question and replace it with the non-debug version. For example, delete *Lib/Debug/System.dcu* and replace it with *Lib/System.dcu*.

Alternatively, if there's one VCL unit that you want to trace through, but are otherwise uninterested in debugging code you didn't write, then disable "Use debug DCUs," and then find the debug version of that DCU and put it in among the non-debug files.

If you accidentally find yourself tracing through a function you're not interested in, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to "step out" of the current function. Eventually, you will learn to recognize the places that typically lead to calls you don't want to trace, and then you'll press <kbd>F8</kbd> to "step over" that code instead of <kbd>F7</kbd> to "step into" it.